# User avatar is misplaced on the badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I think that the avatar, name and rep of a user are misplaced on the [badge page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/enthusiast?userid=133955).

Here is a picture with freehand circles:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just pushed a fix. This will be live in the next production build.